# Adding a custom jar to grails project

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

We have a custom security jar that was built off of spring security core and spring security cas by another team and we would like to add it to our Grails project. I added the `<import resource=classpath:META-INF/security.xml>` tag to my applicationContext.xml and tried adding the required xmlns and xsd declarations, but it is giving me an error.

```
Message: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/security.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/security.xml]
```

We had to manually add the spring-security-core, spring-security-conf dependencies when we upgraded our pure java project to use this jar, do we need to do the same with Grails or is there a better way?

Grails 2.2
Groovy 2.0.6

And the security.jar was built with Spring Security 3.0

Any guidance? I've looked through the three Grails books we have and not one of them touches on adding custom libraries to your project.

Thanks.

Edit 1.

Added the spring security dependencies to the BuildConfig.groovy file as below

```
    dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.4.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.4.RELEASE"
}
```

Which seemed to get me past the old error. But now I'm getting the lovely

```
Error 2013-06-25 16:20:34,982 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [edu.umt.security.NetIdAuthoritiesPopulator] for bean with name 'userService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.umt.security.NetIdAuthoritiesPopulator
...
Caused by CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [edu.umt.security.NetIdAuthoritiesPopulator] for bean with name 'userService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.umt.security.NetIdAuthoritiesPopulator
```

Usually we fix this by cleaning the eclipse project a few times and it works itself out, no dice this time and I'm not sure where the problem is. I can see the class in question inside the jar file, so I know it's there.

Answer (score 1):

If a jar isn't available in a Maven repo and you can't add a dependency in BuildConfig.groovy, you can add it to the lib directory, but it's not automatically discovered. Run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get it added to the classpath.

Comment: So I added these
runtime "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.4.RELEASE"
runtime "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.4.RELEASE"
to my BuildConfig, but it's saying error failed to resolve.

Comment: Nevermind that previous comment, it helps if you put them in the right section. I had them under plugins, and they belong in dependencies obviously.

Comment: I managed to pull the jar down using a private maven repo, however I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException when I try and add the import to ApplicationContext.xml. Is there a different way of importing resources in grails?